# My conditional statement in my coffee script is returning a boolean when it should return a number

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, boolean, conditional-statements

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  In my coffee script, I have

```
    console.log(hours) 
    hours = (hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours)
    console.log(hours)
```

but I’m getting some strange results.  In the first line, console.log is printing out “14” (a number), but in the next console.log, it prints out “false”.  I don’t understand why this is happening.  It should remain “14”.  What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
hours = (hours < 10 ? "0" + hours.to_s : hours)
```

Comment: Doing that produces the error, "SyntaxError: [stdin]:32:48: unexpected :" when I load the page.  Keep in mind htis is a coffee script, not a Ruby script.